How to fail temporal activity with non-retriable
all.
This is my code for creating workflow:
return $workflowClient->newWorkflowStub(
            static::class,
            WorkflowOptions::new()
                ->withTaskQueue(config()->get('workflow.taskQueue'))
                ->withRetryOptions(
                    RetryOptions::new()
                        ->withNonRetryableExceptions([NonRetryableActivityException::class])
                        ->withInitialInterval(CarbonInterval::seconds((int) env('WORKFLOW_RETRY_INITIAL_INTERVAL_SECONDS', 1)))
                        ->withMaximumAttempts((int) env('WORKFLOW_RETRY_MAXIMUM_ATTEMPTS', 3))
                )
                ->withSearchAttributes($customSearchAttributes)

And my activity code:
#[ReturnType(Type::TYPE_STRING)]
    #[ActivityMethod(name: '.executeWebHook')]
    public function executeWebHook(string $path, array $entityData): string
    {
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.api+json',
        ])->post($path, $entityData);

        if (in_array($response->status(), [
            SymfonyResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,
            SymfonyResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
            SymfonyResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND,
        ], true)
        ) {
            throw new ApplicationFailure(
                $response->body(),
                NonRetryableActivityException::class,
                true
            );
        }

        return $response->body();
    }

But, my activity retrying and ignoring NonRetryableActivityException::class type
